# I can't move or dump items that were dropped by Dwarfs interrupted in a task

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I had two dwarfs build a wall when they were interrupted by the werefox Iño Enemtuthru. Apparently a large fox twisted into a humanoid form is enough to drop everything and start running.

The problem is I can't get rid of those two dropped granite blocks.. They are marked for dumping, but noone has picked them up in a long time and now they are blocking further constructions.
What can I do to convince the dwarfs to pick them up? Is it a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the "build a wall here" designation/order is still standing, the blocks are marked as being "in use" for this task. The quickest way is to abort the build order using <kbd>t</kbd>, navigating to the not yet built walls, and pressing <kbd>x</kbd> to abort their construction. Then you can order them re-built if you want to.

Comment: Ah! It didn't occur to me to cancel the wall building-task.  I found another item (a door) that had no outstanding building instructions and was stuck the same way. I forbade it, waited a bit and then reclaimed it. After that a Dwarf came by and obediently picked it up to take it to the stockpile. Thanks for your quick reply! You were right.